# Functions run before button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm calling a chain of functions through one click function, like below (simplified from my actual code). The problem is, `initMap()` is running before the user clicks the `<button>`, throwing an error, because the `latitude`/`longitude` are not defined until the user inputs an address through the `click()` function.

How can I prevent `initMap()` from running before the `click()` function?

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var user_search = $("input").val();
  var url = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + user_search + ".json?access_token=MYAPIKEY";
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var number = data.features[0].address;
      var route = data.features[0].text;
      var latitude = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1];
      var longitude = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
      initMap(latitude, longitude);
  });
});

var map;
var infowindow;

// Create Google Map with location at center

function initMap(latitude, longitude) {
  var location = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};
  console.log(location);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: location,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: location,
    radius: 3200,
    types: ['school']
  }, callback);
}

// List nearby places

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      listPlaces(results[i]);
    }
  }

  else {
    alert("There was an error finding address data.")
  }
}

// ONLY list places with characteristics below
function listPlaces(place) {
  if (place.name.indexOf('High ') > -1 && place.name.indexOf('Junior') == -1)  {
    $('body').append('<br>' + place.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on the code you shared, I don't think it'll run without being clicked, also the syntax of the code you shared is incorrect.

Comment: It is unlikely that the `initMap` function will run before a button is clicked, unless you call it in some other portion of your code not shown in your question.

Comment: show us your html code.

Comment: Your initMap function has syntax error. Callback is present outside of that InitMap's bracket. Please correct it first.

Comment: I posted the full code (minus mapbox api key).

Comment: it is a google api initMap will be automatically called from the map file u included.set default value for latitude and longitude

Comment: yep.. I took it off the script tag in my HTML, and it is no longer being called.

Comment: without that file u can't create maps

Comment: Oh I see, but that's okay, I am actually not creating a map with this. I'm using it for the places API. I'd like to take the map section out, but it causes errors with the places api. I may post a new question.

Comment: dont remove tat file instead of tat search for api setting which stops calling that function initial loading in google map apis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100212/discussion-between-sundar-and-user1661677).

Answer (score 0):

ur  initMap function is not getting closed properly.the error is because of syntax error not because of initMap() running without button click

```
$("button").click(function() {
      initMap(latitude, longitude);
});

function initMap(latitude, longitude) {
     //do stuff
callback();
  } 

function callback(results, status) {
  //do stuff
}

function listPlaces(place) {
   //do more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this is the real code you want?

```
$("button").click(function() {
      initMap(latitude, longitude);
});

function initMap(latitude, longitude) {
     //do stuff
}

function callback(results, status) {
  //do stuff
}

function listPlaces(place) {
   //do more stuff
}
```